# I designed an opamp, any additions on how to make it better? (Closer to ideal opamp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, bjt, npn

I'm not very good at electronics, but after learning for a bit, I designed a bare minimum opamp which has a differential amplifier and a Darlington NPN amplifier. Here is a picture:

[image: Opamp Circuit design, Not Tested]

I thought about adding a buffer network before the differential amplifier, but I have a limit: 6 NPN transistors.
Edit:

Edit:
I thought about adding a high input impedance single transistor buffer with pulldown resistor before the inputs to increase input impedance (closer to ideal opamp), does anyone have a better circuit layout to use these transistors?

Comment: Where to start?

Comment: Opamp designers are generally not shy about throwing transistors at the problem. They're a bit more reluctant to employ resistors.

Comment: @periblepsis I'd start by asking what purpose each resistor serves.

Comment: @JohnDoty I just look at it and all kinds of things come to mind... starting with the output stage. But dozens of other thoughts intrude. I'm flummoxed about where to start. It's a mess. There is little right about it. So I'll leave it to you. Have at it.

Comment: Probably, the circuit will work as a linear amplifier for a certain dimensioning. However, in this context one must ask for example - what is the purpose of R1 and R5?

Comment: The question title contains ``any suggestions on how to make it better?``. What sort of improvements are you looking for? E.g. (a) reducing power consumption (b) increasing bandwidth (c) Reducing [Inherent Circuit Noise](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/r13an0010-noise-calculations-op-amp-circuits)

Comment: R1, R2, R3 and R5 modulate the current to the transistors so as to not fry them, R1 is more of a wire resistance, so it's very low. R4 ends the differential amplifier and without R6 there is no pulldown to V- when the transistor isn't open so all the resistors serve a purpose

Comment: When I ask to "Make it better" I intend (as stated in the title) to bring its performance nearer to the ideal opamp, maybe being used as a substitute for certain opamps while having the least transistors possible.

Comment: @TheAmplifier How can you fry the transistors when all the current must pass through either R4 or R6?

Comment: I have room for only 6 transistors max. I don't have a lot of transistors and I don't want to buy opamps

Comment: If you don't have room, why waste space on resistors?

Comment: @JohnDoty  R4 can be also viewed as wire resistance but R6 is a pulldown resistor so it also isn't that big. I was thinking about modulating collector current, but your suggestion makes sense. Remove all resistors except R4 and R6, thank you

Comment: @JohnDoty I have room, the problem is the transistor number

Comment: @TheAmplifier Resistors take up a lot more area than transistors do.

Comment: Wthout R3 - what will be the input for the last stage?

Comment: By eliminating R2 and R3, the first stage now always has the same output, and doesn't respond at all to the input.

Answer (score 0):

If 6 transistors is the bare maximum, it becomes a kind of codegolf challenge to obtain the most "opamp-like" behavior possible.

I'd use them as follows: (all polarities can be flipped of course)

- 2 NPN for the input pair.
- 2 PNP as current mirror on the two input collectors
- 1 PNP in CE config as a second/output stage

This leaves one more that can be used for something useful:

1 NPN as crude constant current sink to keep the tail current constant.

Comment: I said to only use NPN transistors, as I don't have any PNP

Comment:  I am not sure one can generate output voltages below approximately input voltage with only NPN...

Comment: You can, but it's a bit silly. Use an interstage attenuator to shift the voltage, make it up with output gain.

Comment: @JohnDoty could you send me a link to a site or other resource because I can't find anything

Comment: @TheAmplifier you form a resistive voltage divider between the stages and use a CE NPN output stage.

Comment: So I would end up using 1 transistor less from the darlington amp to the ce amp

Comment: @TheAmplifier the CE stage alone has a high output impedance. So following it up with another output buffer is certainly not a bad idea.

Comment: I doubt there's any resource on design of opamps with only NPN transistors.

Answer (score 0):

R1 doesn't do anything to help the gain -- eliminate it and increase R2 & R3 to compensate.

You actually don't even need R2 (replace with a short). It helps control input offset, but the loading of the output Darlington already unbalances things.

T3 (the 1st device in the Darlington) doesn't have a controlled bias, so it will have poor bandwidth. Give it a controlled bias by adding a resistor between its emitter and GND, or between its emitter and the output.